# Magento 2 $quote->getAllItems(); does not working properly

Tags: magento, magento2

Try to catch the quote items in an after sale process, it's working fine. But when quote is not in default website, the request is empty. Why? Thanks!
This is the code:

```
  $orderId = 123;
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $quoteToOrder = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem');
  $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
  $quote = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote')->load($order->getQuoteId());

  $items = $quote->getAllItems();

  foreach ($items as $quoteItem) ...
```

Its not an extension from checkout or cart, it's an after sale process that starts before order shipped through cron.

Answer (score 1):

As of Magento-2.0, the service contracts in Magento_Checkout and Magento_Quote do not provide the necessary methods yet, so we use the cart model. In your plugin inject it like this:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart)
{
    $this->cart = $cart;
}
```

Now that you have access to the cart, you can retrieve the items in several ways, which is basically the same as in Magento 1:

> $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection()

Returns a quote item collection with all items associated to the current quote.

> $this->cart->getItems()

This is a shortcut for the method above, but if there is no quote it returns an empty array, so you cannot rely on getting a collection instance.

> $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllItems()

Loads the item collection, then returns an array of all items which are not marked as deleted (i.e. have been removed in the current request).

> $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems()

Loads the item collection, then returns an array of all items which are not marked as deleted AND do not have a parent (i.e. you get items for bundled and configurable products but not their associated children). Each array item corresponds to a displayed row on the cart page.

Choose what fits your needs best. In most cases, the last method is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But with this solution, it's only possible to catch items from the current session. But in this case, it's an after sales process and I do not need items of current session, I need items from a specific orderID. Or i'm wrong?  So how to expand this to achieve my goal?

Comment: `quote.getAllItems()` worked for me in checkout page where `quote` is `define(['Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'], function (quote) {...});`. Thanks a lot.